# mySQL cluster licensing and support

Tags: mysql, cluster-computing

we are looking at using mySQL cluster GPL version in our product.
If we need support and bug fix of this version, the only way is to buy CGE cluster from oracle with support or is there also a community support that can fix bugs on this code? or maybe other companies that can support the community version and are able to fix bugs within github version?

Answer (score 0):

We at MariaDB did provide MySQL Cluster support in the past, but we never did any actual code fixes for that storage engine, and by now have discontinued supporting it.

SeveralNines provide management software that supports MySQL Cluster, but I'm not sure whether they also provide support for Cluster itself. It might be worth asking them.

FromDual does not list MySQL Cluster as a supported product, but I know that they have some MySQL Cluster knowledge on board, so it can't harm to ask there, too.

But when it comes to actual code fixes, MySQL/Oracle will be your only choice I'm afraid.

Comment: thanks I will check these options. I assume in any case Oracle is updating the software in the git so I can always get the latest version right (even without support from them).